# AWS Elastic Bean Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create an environment on a AWS ElasticBean, but I keep getting the error:

> Stack named 'awseb-e-imwsxv2x9n-stack' aborted operation. Current
>   state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create: [AWSEBLoadBalancer, AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata,
>   AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitHandle].

Can someone please point to where/how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the EB logs via the console?  Any more informative information there?

Comment: Well, thats the only error message I get there.

Comment: I think @Brooks means these logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html which will give you more details about the error on the instance

Comment: Yes, hopefully that will provide more information, though I tried searching for that exact error and wasn't able to find any other reports of it.  I found similar ones, but nothing exactly the same.

Comment: It sounds weird that it wouldn't be anything more in the logs. Have you tried to terminate and recreate the environment?

Comment: Hi all, I was able to figure it out. It was a problem with the VPC default not existing. I just has to add the --vpc, and fill in the details. I have mange to deploy what I wanted. Many thanks to all of you.